# How to shrinkwrap flat objects on a curved surface when using geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

Using geometry nodes how can I "shrinkwrap" or array these instances of objects flat against a curved object?

[image]

geometry nodes set up https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zjyrx.jpg

another photo https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBvjP.jpg

Comment: you didn't say with one word what you wanna have!? The objects are already on your surface. Shrinkwrap wouldn't make it another way. Show us a picture of what you want to have or describe it in words. Picture would be easier.

Answer (score 1):

The ball is ico sphere,but it's just to make it looks nicer. You can't spread your cube on the sphere uniform,just a little similar.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response! I'm having some difficulty still with the instances not being "shrinkwrapped" or flattened onto the curved mesh. Here are a couple of photos of the issue. https://imgur.com/oRSpPyB https://imgur.com/5beoy7g